# Hiding watermark for first page?

Tags: xwatermark

I haven't seen a question on this website that deals with hiding watermarks with `xwatermark`. Here's the preamble of the document I'm working on that is relevant:

```
\usepackage[printwatermark]{xwatermark}
\newwatermark*[page=1, textmark=]{}
\newwatermark*[allpages,color=gray,angle=0,scale=1,xpos=46,ypos=-134]{Some watermark}
```

In section 3.2 of the [documentation](http://mirrors.ibiblio.org/CTAN/macros/latex/contrib/xwatermark/doc/xwatermark-guide.pdf):

> If you issue any of the statements
>
> ```
> page=x 
> pages=x-y 
> pagex={x,y,z} 
> firstpage 
> lastpage 
> allpages=true 
> evenpages=true 
> oddpages=true
> ```
>
> together with `printwatermark=true` but you don’t want the mark on any particular
>   page, we can simply set `\newwatermark[other keys,textmark=]{}` or, to
>   the same eﬀect, we may set `\newwatermark[other keys]{}`, where ‘other
>   keys’ may include the page speciﬁers.

I'm trying to hide the watermark for the first page. As you see in the code above, I have `\newwatermark*[page=1, textmark=]{}`. I have also tried using `firstpage` instead of `page = 1`, and I have also tried placing this line after `\newwatermark*[allpages,color=gray,angle=0,scale=1,xpos=46,ypos=-134]{Some watermark}`.

Can someone explain what I'm doing wrong?

MWE: as far as I could tell, this is the minimum necessary to get the watermark to look exactly how I need it to.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage[margin=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[version=3]{mhchem}
\usepackage [english]{babel}
\usepackage[printwatermark]{xwatermark}\newwatermark*[pages=2-,color=gray,angle=0,scale=1,xpos=46,ypos=-134]{\footnotesize Copyright \textcopyright\:2014 by some company.}
\begin{document}
Stuff
\newpage 
More stuff
\end{document}
```

Received an error, as mentioned in the comments: `No end-page for page-range of watermark: ||||I have used the default end-page '5' instead.`

Comment: I don't know the package but can you say something like `page=2-` rather than `allpages` for the watermarked case? Otherwise, please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: It gives me an error `" No end-page for page-range of watermark: ||||I have used the default end-page '5' instead.` when I do `2-`. I will post up a MWE probably sometime tomorrow.

Comment: MWE has been posted.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can skip the first page by selecting the pages

```
..., page=2-\lastdocpage, ...
```

in your options. `\lastdocpage` references the last page in the document.