# How can I refer to the page number corresponding to \lastdocpage - 2?

Tags: watermark, xwatermark

Follow-up question to [Hiding watermark for first page?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/191477/hiding-watermark-for-first-page).

I have recently learned about `\lastdocpage` (from the previous question), but is there a way to refer to two pages *prior* to `\lastdocpage`? To understand the context, the watermark from the previous question should last from pages 2 to *two pages* prior to the end of the document.

MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[margin=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[version=3]{mhchem}
\usepackage [english]{babel}
\usepackage[printwatermark]{xwatermark}
\newwatermark*[pages=2-\lastdocpage,color=gray,angle=0,scale=1,xpos=46,ypos=-134]{\footnotesize Copyright \textcopyright\:2014 by some company.}
\begin{document}
Stuff
\newpage 
More stuff
\end{document}
```

In this MWE, the watermark is on pages 2 to `\lastdocpage`. I have tried `\pages=2-{\lastdocpage-2}`but this did not work.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

According to the [manual of `xwatermark`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/xwatermark) you should be able to write

```
pages=2-{\lastdocpage-2}
```

Indeed the manual contains the example

```
pages={\lastdocpage-2}-\lastdocpage
```

However, while the last version works, the first throws an error.  Explicitly forcing it to a number as follows does however work:

```
pages=2-{\number\numexpr\lastdocpage-2}
```

So a complete document would be:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage[margin=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[version=3]{mhchem}
\usepackage [english]{babel}
\usepackage[printwatermark]{xwatermark}

\newwatermark*[pages=2-{\number\numexpr\lastdocpage-2},color=gray,angle=0,scale=1,xpos=46,ypos=-134]{\footnotesize Copyright \textcopyright\:2014 by some company.}

\begin{document}
Stuff
\newpage 
More stuff
\newpage
Third page
\newpage
Fourth page

\end{document}
```

[The above requires you have a standard modern tex engine that includes the `etex` features.]

Comment: Your version is definitely much easier ;-)

Answer (score 3):

You have to save the value of `\lastdocpage` to a counter and decrease the counter by the appropiate value, i.e. in this case by two. Afterwards it is possible to use the counter value as end limit of the watermarks.

To use the counter value of `lastwatermarkpage`, it is possible either

- saying `\thelastwatermarkpage`
- `\number\value{lastwatermarkpage}`  which guarantess, that the output is a number, whereas `\thelastwatermark` is a command, which can basically redefined to do anything else, so usage is discouraged.

I have used a `\forloop` to generate some dummy pages. In the production run, this can be removed of course, as well as the `loopcounter` definition.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[margin=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[version=3]{mhchem}
\usepackage [english]{babel}
\usepackage[printwatermark]{xwatermark}

\usepackage{forloop}

\newcounter{loopcounter}

\newcounter{lastwatermarkpage}
\setcounter{lastwatermarkpage}{\lastdocpage}
\addtocounter{lastwatermarkpage}{-2}%

\newwatermark*[pages=2-{\number\value{lastwatermarkpage}},color=gray,angle=0,scale=1,xpos=46,ypos=-134]{\footnotesize Copyright \textcopyright\:2014 by some company.}
\begin{document}
\forloop{loopcounter}{1}{\number\value{loopcounter} < 22}{%
Some stuff
\clearpage

}%
\end{document}
```